# How to use Bitshares JS in my Angular Web App

Tags: javascript, angular, blockchain, cryptocurrency

I download the BitsharesJS library from https://github.com/bitshares/bitsharesjs.git.

Referring the guide I should import need classes in my component, say for example I can use [accountLogin](https://bitsharesjs.bitshares.org/variable/index.html#static-variable-accountLogin) for account login, but I am not sure how to use this library in my component in Angular.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you used this command `npm install bitsharesjs` ?

Comment: yes, I can see bitsharesjs and bitsharesjs-ws directories in node_modules.

Comment: Try to import like this in your component `import * as BitShare from 'bitsharesjs';` and check in console by `console.log(JSON.stringify(BitShare));`

Comment: when I tried, I am getting an error - `Could not find a declaration file for module bitsharesjs`

Comment: Well, that suggestions works at my end. Might be angular different versions issue.

Comment: @hrdkisback May I know your Angular version which works for you?

Comment: Yeah, It is `"@angular/cli": "~8.3.3",` and `"@angular/compiler": "~8.2.4"`

Comment: Ok. I also trying to use `bitsharesjs-ws`. After installing it in Angular app, the folder `node_modules/bitsharesjs-ws` doesn't have any `dist` or `example` folder.

Comment: I only checked with `bitsharesjs`, I think `bitsharesjs-ws` used for web sockets.